# Redis: Delete user token by email ( find Key by Value )

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have followed tutorial on how to create token-based authentication with node from this tutorial http://www.kdelemme.com/2014/08/16/token-based-authentication-with-nodejs-redis/

I got it all worked out, but I got 1 problem.

The way I store token is :

KEY = TOKEN

VALUE = UserData (Username, email, etc.)

To protect multiple devices login, I would like to invalidate the existing Token, and generate new one. During login, I would like to check if the user's token is already existed. However, I need to find Key by Value. ( I need to find TOKEN by email ). But as I look through Redis document I couldn't find any line talking about finding Key by value.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have to choose one of two approaches: a full scan of the database or an index. A full scan, as proposed in another answer to this question, will be quite inefficient - you'll go over your entire keyspace (or at least all the tokens) and will need to fetch each one until you find a match to the email.

An index will allow you to get an answer to your query much faster, at the expense of some RAM and administrative overhead. While Redis doesn't provide indexing capabilities out of the box, you can easily devise them using regular Redis data structures and operations. For example, the straightforward way to accomplish what you want would be to store for each token another key who's name is the email and its value the token. This will let you let the token but email with a single GET operation.

Note that this indexing approach will effectively double the number of token-related keys, so in order to optimize your RAM consumption you may want to consider other types of indexing structures (e.g. using a Hash to group email-token pairs where the is used as a  bucket).

Comment: So I will have 2 key value pair for each person right?
For example, 123456 => abc@abc.com and abc@abc.com => 123456.

I will do research about optimizing this 


( after you mention about indexing , I found great tutorial on indexing Redis and this should also be helpful to others. This is the link to it)
http://www.slideshare.net/itamarhaber/20140922-redis-tlv-redis-indices
Thanks ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the kind feedback and feel free to reach out with any question :)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do a [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) of some kind and iterate through the keys, searching each value. The `redis` module supports these commands, but if you need/want a streaming interface for SCAN, there are at least a couple of modules to do that: [`redis-scanstreams`](https://github.com/brycebaril/redis-scanstreams) and [`redisscan`](https://github.com/fritzy/node-redisscan) (which technically uses a callback approach, so not a real stream implementation).

Comment: While a valid answer, this approach will not perform too well as it requires a full database scan and fetch. Indexing your data appears to be a better approach to solving this.

Comment: Sure, if you want to maintain that.